# Mock Azure Storage Blob in java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

Can anyone guide me how can I mock azure Blob Storage in Java SDK.

I want to mock connection String, SAS token, endpoint, containerName. If all these got mock, then it will be easy to mock BlobClient.

For reference code is-

public BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient(){
return new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString("TESTING STRING").buildClient();
}

Comment: Would the [Azurite emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio) be a useful alternative to your case?

Comment: Please check if that will be helpful : https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.3.0/com/azure/storage/blob/BlobClientBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

To workaround this issue you can keep the values of connection String, SAS token, endpoint, ContainerName using their respective variable in a file under the same project.
You can mock the blobClient using the below statement by passing the above-mentioned objects in the code.

```
BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClientBuilder()
    .endpoint("<your-storage-account-url>")
    .sasToken("<your-sasToken>")
    .containerName("mycontainer")
    .blobName("myblob")
    .buildClient();
```

or

```
// Only one "?" is needed here. If the sastoken starts with "?", please removing one "?".
BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClientBuilder()
    .endpoint("<your-storage-account-url>" + "/" + "mycontainer" + "/" + "myblob" + "?" + "<your-sasToken>")
    .buildClient();
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-java-stable